# Proving a function differ by a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be entire functions such that $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$
>
> Prove: $f(z)=c\cdot g(z)$ s.t $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|c|<1$

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ implies that $g$ is never zero. Therefore $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is a bounded entire function, hence is constant.

Comment: Why is $h(z)$ bounded? as a dvision of 2 entire functions?

Comment: Because $\displaystyle\left|\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right|<1$ by hypothesis.